# Prove that if $ \ f(x) g(x)=0_R \ $ then there exists $ \ c \in R \ $ such that $ \ cg(x)=0_R \ $

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $ \ R \ $ be a commutative ring and let $ \ f(x), g(x) \in R[x] \ $ with $ \ f(x) \ $ is non-zero.

Prove that if $ \ f(x) g(x)=0_R \ $ then there exists $ \ c \in R \ $  such that $ \ cg(x)=0_R \ $.

**Answer:**

let $ \ 0 \neq f(x) =c \in R[x] \ $

Then,

$ f(x)g(x)=0_R \\ \Rightarrow c g(x)=0_R \ $

But this becomes short answer.

please help me with correct answer.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your proof... Are you sure you have the question right? Maybe it's required that $c$ is nonzero?

Comment: You need $c\in R$, not $c\in R[x]$.

Comment: Yes it is given $ \  c \in R \ $ only

Comment: I think he is referring to your first line under "Answer" where you wrote $c \in R[x]$. But that's only a small thing, right @EricWofsey? Everything else is good?

Comment: That's certainly not a small thing, because you don't know that $f(x)\in R$.

Comment: If I do in this way:  Let $ f(x)=c h(x) , \ c \in R , \ 0 \neq h(x) \in R[x] \ $ , then  $ f(x)g(x)=0_R \ \Rightarrow ch(x)g(x)=0_R \Rightarrow c(h(x))^{-1} h(x)g(x)=h(x)^{-1}0_R \Rightarrow cg(x)=0_R \ $. Is this way correct?

Comment: Is my approach correct?

Comment: I don't think so. You cannot usually take multiplicative inverses in polynomial rings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:**

This solution works in general. Suppose that $f(x)g(x)=0$ with $f(x)\neq 0$. If $g(x) = 0$, then any of the non-zero coefficients will work. Otherwise, we do the following: first, write $f(x)$ as $a_0 + a_1 + \cdots + a_k x^k$ and $g(x)$ as $b_0 + b_1 + \cdots + b_n x^n$. Observe that $a_kb_n=0$. Now, if $b_nf(x) \neq 0$, then we proceed by considering $(b_nf(x))g(x)$ and note that the degree of $b_nf(x)$ is strictly less than $f(x)$. If $f(x)$ is only left with one term, i.e. only one of the $b_na_i \neq 0$, then this $b_na_i$ works. On the other hand, If $b_nf(x)=0$, then for each of the $a_i$, $a_ib_n = 0$. Then we look at $g(x) - b_nx^n$ of degree strictly less than $g(x)$. If this new polynomial is $0$ then we had that $g(x) = b_nx^n$ and any of the coefficients of $f(x)$ will work. We proceed by induction.

The result will be that $c$ is a product of one of the $a_i$ with a product of powers of the $b_j$.

**Edit: this only works if we can be assured that $a_n^p \neq 0$ which is not true in a general commutative ring**

Say that $f(x) = a_0+a_1x+\cdots+a_nx^n, g(x) = b_0+b_1x+\cdots+b_kx^k$. Since $f(x)g(x)=0$, we get that $a_nb_k=0,a_{n-1}b_k+a_nb_{k-1}=0,\cdots$. Multiplying the second equation by $a_n$ gives $a_n^2b_{k-1}=0.$ For the next equation, multiply by $a_n^2$ to get $a_n^3b_{k-2}=0$. Continue like this to get that there is some power $p$ of $a_n$ such that for each $i$, $a_n^pb_i=0$. Then $a_n^pg(x)=0$

Comment: where we used the condition $ \ f(x) \ $ is non-zero?

Comment: How do you ensure that $a_n^p\neq 0$?

Comment: You are right. This only works if we have additional properties on $R$. The OP did not say that $R$ is an integral domain or anything like that

Comment: Ok, I updated the solution